# Align cards next to each other when the screen is resized

Tags: html, css

I have cards that are aligned next to each other on full screen, but when I resize the screen they go one under each other, how to have them always aligned horizontally? I would also like to resize them accordingly so that the content is justified.

```css
.actions {
  justify-content: center;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 15px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 400px;
}

.cards {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 200px;
  width: calc(100/4);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #95a7b7;
  margin: auto;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px 80px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="actions">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="content">
        <h2><a href="#"> About </a></h1>
          <p> Here you can find more about myself </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="content">
        <h2><a href="#"> Interest </a></h1>
          <p> Here you can find the list of my interests and the blogs that I have created</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="content">
        <h2><a href="#"> Notes </a></h1>
          <p> Here you can find the list of my notes and things that I like to keep track of. You might not be able to access to all informatio</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dont use `float` for styling purpose. `float` is for floating images within a text block only. For everythign else use `flexbox` or `css-grid`. In this case `flexbox` is the easier way and you can change the direction with `flex-direction`. PS: `justify-content` only works in combination with flex or grid. It has no effect on inline-block elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are perfectly okay to got with `display: flex`, go with this approach.

- Add `display: flex` to `.actions`
- Add `display: flex; flex: 0 1 200px;` to `.column`. This will set `flex-grow: 0`, `flex-shrink: 1` and `flex-basis: 200px;` This will the element a maximum width of 200px and shrink below that if resized.

  ```css
  .actions {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 15px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }

  .cards {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 200px;
    width: calc(100/4);
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #95a7b7;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .column {
    /* float: left; */
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="content">
          <h2><a href="#"> About </a></h1>
            <p> Here you can find more about myself </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="content">
          <h2><a href="#"> Interest </a></h1>
            <p> Here you can find the list of my interests and the blogs that I have created</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="content">
          <h2><a href="#"> Notes </a></h1>
            <p> Here you can find the list of my notes and things that I like to keep track of. You might not be able to
              access to all informatio</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that is improving everything a lot. I now need to tweak something for the text but is working a lot better, gonna check the properties you put as I didn't know them before.

Comment: Done. Just a question, my cards resize according to the h2 element length, which makes the text go outside the card, but I would like that each card keep the same width when the screen resizes, any suggestions for what may cause it?

Comment: @LasSincas add `max-width: 100%;` to `.column` that will work

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

- I made **actions** div to display flex, so all columns get align next to each other and set justify-content:space-between.

```css
.actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 1120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.cards {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 200px;
  width: calc(100/4);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #95a7b7;
  margin: auto;
}

.column {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="actions">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="content">
        <h2><a href="#"> About </a></h1>
          <p> Here you can find more about myself </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="content">
        <h2><a href="#"> Interest </a></h1>
          <p> Here you can find the list of my interests and the blogs that I have created</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="content">
        <h2><a href="#"> Notes </a></h1>
          <p> Here you can find the list of my notes and things that I like to keep track of. You might not be able to access to all informatio</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems it is doing what I was looking for. Now I only need to keep the 'actions' div always present when the screen resizes. For example when the screen is less than 1000px I can only see the first card, but I would like to move them so that I can still see all. Any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: just set .action class to overflow-x:scroll; in media query.

Answer (score 0):

the real qustion is how did you get it to go under each other bc i need that

```css
.actions {
  justify-content: center;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 15px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 400px;
}

.cards {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 200px;
  width: calc(100/4);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #95a7b7;
  margin: auto;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px 80px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="actions">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="content">
        <h2><a href="#"> About </a></h1>
          <p> Here you can find more about myself </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="content">
        <h2><a href="#"> Interest </a></h1>
          <p> Here you can find the list of my interests and the blogs that I have created</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="content">
        <h2><a href="#"> Notes </a></h1>
          <p> Here you can find the list of my notes and things that I like to keep track of. You might not be able to access to all informatio</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```